# How to unmarshall wrapped xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My xml file looks like below and I try to unmarshall it.

```
<Projects 
xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<Project>
    <projectId 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">1
    </projectId>
    <projectName 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">project1
    </projectName>
    <startDate 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2014-09-09T00:00:00.000-07:00
    </startDate>
    <endDate 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2015-09-09T00:00:00.000-07:00
    </endDate>
    <projectManagerUserId 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">3167
    </projectManagerUserId>
    <statusId 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2
    </statusId>
    <teamId 
        xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">2
    </teamId>
</Project>
</Projects>
```

My bean classes looks like below,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Project {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String projectId;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String projectName;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String startDate;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String endDate;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String projectManager;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String status;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String teamId;

public Project() {
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getProjectManager() {
    return projectManager;
}

public void setProjectManager(String projectManager) {
    this.projectManager = projectManager;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTeamId() {
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(String teamId) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
}

public String getProjectId() {
    return projectId;
}

public void setProjectId(String projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}
}
```

My other bean,

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProjectCollection {

    @XmlElement(name="Project")
    private List<Project> projects;

    public ProjectCollection() {
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }
}
```

But this does not work as expected. Can someone point out what's the wrong with this code.?

Comment: Provided xml have nothing in common with classes, is there a chance you've pasted a wrong xml?

Comment: Nothing returns when I try to access .getProjectName()

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you need to fix:

### Specify the Root Element

By default JAXB will think the root element is `projectCollection`, you can change it to match your XML as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Projects") 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ProjectCollection {
```

### Map the Namespace Qualification

Since your XML document is namespace qualified you need to map this.  This can be done using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.  Change the package in the fragment below to match your own.  Note:  The exact content below goes in a source file called `package-info.java` with the exact contents shown below with the package name to match that of your model.

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

I have written more about JAXB and namespace qualification on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

### Change the `@XmlAttribute` Annotations to  `@XmlElement`

You have a lot of fields annotation with `@XmlAttribute`, but in your XML they are elements.  You can either make this change or leave the `@XmlElement` annotation off completely since it is the default.

Comment: When I use "@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)" it says "@XmlSchema not applicable to type"

Comment: @MaDu_LK - You need to put it in a file called `package-info.java` with only the contents given in my answer.

Comment: I added the package-info but it says top level element is not completed.

Comment: @MaDu_LK - Can you edit your question to include the exception you are getting?